# Code Contract understanding of error

Tags: .net-4.0, code-contracts

I am just getting started with Code Contracts, and need a little help in correcting an error:

Given this code:

```
class MyClass
{
    private bool _isUsed = false;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Contract.Requires(!_isUsed);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error CC1038: Member 'MyClass._isUsed' has less visibility than the enclosing method 'MyClass.SomeMethod'
```

which seems to makes alot of the standard checks unavailable.  What am I missing in this example?

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/codecontracts/thread/b89bd560-340a-4ab3-8ec9-c80e3120bf1f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a public method SomeMethod.  However, you're requiring that a private member variable is set to false.  You provide no way of setting _isUsed, and so you're putting a check on a variable that a caller has no control over.

You could make _isUsed into a property i.e.

```
public bool IsUsed {get; set;}
```

And then in your SomeMethod() have

```
Contract.Requires(!IsUsed);
```

Answer (score 8):

It has already been explained that either `_isUsed` has visibility issues (caller does not have control) which is rightly enforced by requires.

However, depending on what you are trying to accomplish with the Contract, `Contract.Assert` may meet your needs.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Contract.Assert(!_isUsed);
}
```

would be valid while the Requires was not.